# QProcess -> read stdout from sftp on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ncurses, qprocess

I am trying to read the output from sftp command on Linux. I call sftp from a Qt Application with QProcess. But I don't get any data from the read() method, which should be the stdout from the process. I connected a slot to the `readyRead` signal before I started the process, so I should not miss any output from the process.

The same Application on Windows, using psftp from PuTTY, works fine, I get all the data I need. I want the same on Linux.

After I started the Process ( `sftp user@host` ), I get a password promt from sftp on the terminal, but not in the stdout. According to ldd, sftp uses libncurses, I think this is the problem. Is there a way to redirect all the output of sftp to stdout without using ncurses?

Sample code:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>

class MyClass : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyClass(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
      connect(&prc, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(read()));
      prc.start("sftp user@host"); // valid user and host in the actual project
   }

public slots:
  void read() {
     qDebug("bytes to read: %d", (int)prc.bytesAvailable());

     QString data = prc.readAll();
     qDebug("readAll: %s", qPrintable(data));

     data = prc.readAllStandardOutput();
     qDebug("readAllStandardOutput: %s", qPrintable(data));

     data = prc.readAllStandardError();
     qDebug("readAllStandardError: %s", qPrintable(data));
  }

protected:
  QProcess prc;
};
```

The problem only exists with `sftp`, for other commands like `ls` or `pwd` (the linux bash ls/pwd, not the ftp ls/pwd) it works.

Comment: Could you show the code for the slot you've connected to `readyRead`. Have you tried using `readAll()` instead of `read()`?

Answer (score 0):

sftp doesn't use curses, you cannot read the prompt because it doesn't use stdout for the password, it opens "/dev/tty" which strace shows to be file descriptor 5.  The same fd is used to read the password.

Comment: Is there a way to force sftp to use stdout? ncurses was just a guess because ldd shows a dependency to libncurses.so

Comment: I could do a fdopen() to that filedescriptor, but this is a bad workaround and no solution in my opinion

Comment: I don't think it would work.  If you open fd 5, it will just open fd 6 instead

Answer (score 0):

Run sftp with the "-b -" command line option.  This puts it into batch mode. In batch mode it reads commands from the specified file (or stdin if you use "-") and writes output to stdout.

But, according to the man page, you must use a non-interactive authentication method. Also, you will get no prompt on stdout when in batch mode.